# How to Add background or change text

Tags: php, jquery, css, mobile

My goal is to create pages with information needed about the movie and with links that redirect to a video host where you will watch it. I found an IMDB php plugin and I am trying to insert in jquery mobile so mobile users will easily find the movies and stream them on their iDevices or any device that supports MP4 formats. Something close to http://freeflix.technoinsidr.com/watch.php?m=tt1190080

I've made this http://ivids.tk/test.php?m=tt0068646 How can  I remove TITLE, YEAR (everything that's in BOLD) and put TITLE with the YEAR on the same line if its possible touse jquery mobile as the design? Is it even possible?

```
<?php

class Imdb
{   
    function getMovieInfo($title)
    {
        $imdbId = $this->getIMDbIdFromGoogle(trim($title));
        if($imdbId === NULL){
            $arr = array();
            $arr['error'] = "No Title found in Search Results!";
            return $arr;
        }
        return $this->getMovieInfoById($imdbId);
    }

    function getMovieInfoById($imdbId)
    {
        $arr = array();
        $imdbUrl = "http://www.imdb.com/title/" . trim($imdbId) . "/";
        $html = $this->geturl($imdbUrl);
        if(stripos($html, "<meta name=\"application-name\" content=\"IMDb\" />") !== false){
            $arr = $this->scrapMovieInfo($html);
            $arr['imdb_url'] = $imdbUrl;
        } else {
            $arr['error'] = "No Title found on IMDb!";
        }
        return $arr;
    }

    function getIMDbIdFromGoogle($title){
        $url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=imdb+" . rawurlencode($title);
        $html = $this->geturl($url);
        $ids = $this->match_all('/<a href="http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/(tt\d+).*?".*?>.*?<\/a>/ms', $html, 1);
        if (!isset($ids[0])) //if Google fails
            return $this->getIMDbIdFromBing($title); //search using Bing
        else
            return $ids[0]; //return first IMDb result
    }

    function getIMDbIdFromBing($title){
        $url = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=imdb+" . rawurlencode($title);
        $html = $this->geturl($url);
        $ids = $this->match_all('/<a href="http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/(tt\d+).*?".*?>.*?<\/a>/ms', $html, 1);
        if (!isset($ids[0]))
            return NULL;
        else
            return $ids[0]; //return first IMDb result
    }

    // Scan movie meta data from IMDb page
    function scrapMovieInfo($html)
    {
        $arr = array();
        $arr['title'] = trim($this->match('/<title>(IMDb \- )*(.*?) \(.*?<\/title>/ms', $html, 2));
        $arr['year'] = trim($this->match('/<title>.*?\(.*?(\d{4}).*?\).*?<\/title>/ms', $html, 1));
        $arr['rating'] = $this->match('/ratingValue">(\d.\d)</ms', $html, 1);
        $arr['genres'] = array();
        foreach($this->match_all('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/ms', $this->match('/Genre.?:(.*?)(<\/div>|See more)/ms', $html, 1), 1) as $m)
            array_push($arr['genres'], $m);

        //Get extra inforation on  Release Dates and AKA Titles
        if($arr['title_id'] != ""){
            $releaseinfoHtml = $this->geturl("http://www.imdb.com/title/" . $arr['title_id'] . "/releaseinfo");
            $arr['also_known_as'] = $this->getAkaTitles($releaseinfoHtml, $usa_title);
            $arr['usa_title'] = $usa_title;
            $arr['release_date'] = $this->match('/Release Date:<\/h4>.*?([0-9][0-9]? (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (19|20)[0-9][0-9]).*?(\(|<span)/ms', $html, 1);
            $arr['release_dates'] = $this->getReleaseDates($releaseinfoHtml);
        }
        $arr['plot'] = trim(strip_tags($this->match('/<p itemprop="description">(.*?)(<\/p>|<a)/ms', $html, 1)));
        $arr['poster'] = $this->match('/img_primary">.*?<img src="(.*?)".*?<\/td>/ms', $html, 1);

        $arr['poster_small'] = "";
        if ($arr['poster'] != '' && strrpos($arr['poster'], "nopicture") === false && strrpos($arr['poster'], "ad.doubleclick") === false) { //Get large and small posters
            $arr['poster_small'] = preg_replace('/_V1\..*?.jpg/ms', "_V1._SY150.jpg", $arr['poster']);
        } else {
            $arr['poster'] = "";
        }
        $arr['runtime'] = trim($this->match('/Runtime:<\/h4>.*?(\d+) min.*?<\/div>/ms', $html, 1));
        if($arr['runtime'] == '') $arr['runtime'] = trim($this->match('/infobar.*?(\d+) min.*?<\/div>/ms', $html, 1));
        $arr['storyline'] = trim(strip_tags($this->match('/Storyline<\/h2>(.*?)(<em|<\/p>|<span)/ms', $html, 1)));

        $arr['language'] = array();
        foreach($this->match_all('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/ms', $this->match('/Language.?:(.*?)(<\/div>|>.?and )/ms', $html, 1), 1) as $m)
            array_push($arr['language'], trim($m));
        $arr['country'] = array();
        foreach($this->match_all('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/ms', $this->match('/Country:(.*?)(<\/div>|>.?and )/ms', $html, 1), 1) as $c)
            array_push($arr['country'], $c);

        if($arr['title_id'] != "") $arr['media_images'] = $this->getMediaImages($arr['title_id']);

        return $arr;
    }

    // Scan all Release Dates
    function getReleaseDates($html){
        $releaseDates = array();
        foreach($this->match_all('/<tr>(.*?)<\/tr>/ms', $this->match('/Date<\/th><\/tr>(.*?)<\/table>/ms', $html, 1), 1) as $r)
        {
            $country = trim(strip_tags($this->match('/<td><b>(.*?)<\/b><\/td>/ms', $r, 1)));
            $date = trim(strip_tags($this->match('/<td align="right">(.*?)<\/td>/ms', $r, 1)));
            array_push($releaseDates, $country . " = " . $date);
        }
        return $releaseDates;
    }

    // Scan all AKA Titles
    function getAkaTitles($html, &$usa_title){
        $akaTitles = array();
        foreach($this->match_all('/<tr>(.*?)<\/tr>/msi', $this->match('/Also Known As(.*?)<\/table>/ms', $html, 1), 1) as $m)
        {
            $akaTitleMatch = $this->match_all('/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/ms', $m, 1);
            $akaTitle = trim($akaTitleMatch[0]);
            $akaCountry = trim($akaTitleMatch[1]);
            array_push($akaTitles, $akaTitle . " = " . $akaCountry);
            if ($akaCountry != '' && strrpos(strtolower($akaCountry), "usa") !== false) $usa_title = $akaTitle;
        }
        return $akaTitles;
    }

    // Collect all Media Images
    function getMediaImages($titleId){
        $url  = "http://www.imdb.com/title/" . $titleId . "/mediaindex";
        $html = $this->geturl($url);
        $media = array();
        $media = array_merge($media, $this->scanMediaImages($html));
        foreach($this->match_all('/<a href="\?page=(.*?)">/ms', $this->match('/<span style="padding: 0 1em;">(.*?)<\/span>/ms', $html, 1), 1) as $p)
        {
            $html = $this->geturl($url . "?page=" . $p);
            $media = array_merge($media, $this->scanMediaImages($html));
        }
        return $media;
    }

    // Scan all media images
    function scanMediaImages($html){
        $pics = array();
        foreach($this->match_all('/src="(.*?)"/ms', $this->match('/<div class="thumb_list" style="font-size: 0px;">(.*?)<\/div>/ms', $html, 1), 1) as $i)
        {
            array_push($pics, preg_replace('/_V1\..*?.jpg/ms', "_V1._SY0.jpg", $i));
        }
        return $pics;
    }

    // ************************[ Extra Functions ]******************************
    function geturl($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        $ip=rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/".rand(3,5).".".rand(0,3)." (Windows NT ".rand(3,5).".".rand(0,2)."; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/".rand(3,5).".0.1");
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $html;
    }

    function match_all($regex, $str, $i = 0)
    {
        if(preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches) === false)
            return false;
        else
            return $matches[$i];
    }

    function match($regex, $str, $i = 0)
    {
        if(preg_match($regex, $str, $match) == 1)
            return $match[$i];
        else
            return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) once more.

Comment: there done. I edit the question.

Comment: Too many questions and yes it might be possible but I don't think people will work on this question giving the fact that you're new, your questions seem more like demands and your code is just an ugly copy/paste. You need to work more on the question if you want people to work on a solution...

Comment: I don't get what your end goal of this is. Give us a higher level of what exactly it is you want to do because what it sounds like is a JS screen scraper which is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really shouldn't be done in jQuery, and you could still use a few lessons in being clear with what you're looking for, but a question is a question, and here is my answer:

```
$('th').hide();
var $titlerow = $('tr td:first'), 
    $yearrow = $('tr:eq(1) td:first'),
    title = $titlerow.text(),
    year = $yearrow.text();

$titlerow.text(title + ' - ' + year);
$yearrow.remove();
```

Some things to note:

- You **should not** be doing this is jQuery. You **should** rearrange your PHP. If the code is copy/pasted, then I suggest reading through it. I'll be honest, I didn't read a single line of what you posted, as it was irrelevant to a client-side question after you give a link.
- You **should** be sure to include jQuery in your site. It is not on the page you linked to. Otherwise, the code I provided will not work.
- You **should** put the above code in document ready. I left that last bit somewhat obfuscated. Reason being is that if you don't understand any of this bullet point, some googling of the terms in it will do you good.

Comment: I wrote my goal and what I am trying to do, I will try out for your code, but I am not sure if it will work because the information I get is using the IMDB link and from imdb it takes the title and year and so on.

Comment: O: thanks but I don't know where to put that code. You ever think it's possible to do something like this http://freeflix.technoinsidr.com/watch.php?m=tt1190080 ? with the code I am using?

Comment: In your jsfiddle its HTML and whenever I copy the php code in HTML, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: What you wish to accomplish will never work with copy/pasting code. You will have to actually learn the languages you are working with first. Period.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for saying it for me, @Chad. I think I wouldn't have said it so nice.